# Ngrok auth token file location

Tags: authentication, token, httpserver, ngrok

In Mac and Window how to change the auth token of ngrok manually

**Reference:** https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/640

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To access configuration file of ngrok**

In terminal follow the steps,

```
cd ~/
vi /Users/sriramkarthick/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml
```

Comment: If any people got a solution better than this please provide me in answers. Thanks in advance and all inputs are welcomed